# SwiftUI - MapAnnotation is showing up in wrong position

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, annotations, mapkit

I am trying to display multiple map annotations to Apple Maps In SwiftUI, but the annotations are showing in some wrong perspective. All positions are displayed bellow their right coordinates. If I zoom in the map, annotations are "travelling" to their normal coordinates. Is there any "perspective" calculated by MapKit and is it possible to switch off this behaviour?

Marker displayed below normal position:
[image: Position of marker]

Marker displayed on his coordinates after zoom in:
[image: Zoom in on the position, the marker is on his good coordinates]

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: What are the dimensions of your image? How much transparent padding around the edge of the image?

Comment: The dimensions are 50x50 and padding is 2px.

Comment: @AsiGivati No, I am still lost. I tried handle with dimensions but without result.

Comment: @TomášSkála i answered you outside of this tree, i had a similar issue and i fixed it. please check maybe it will help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this issue and i fixed it by changing the y position of the annotation to 1.0 like so:

```
MapAnnotation(coordinate: job.coordinates!, anchorPoint:.init(x:0.5, y:1.0))
```